# Javascript: Create and move a window with setInterval

Tags: javascript, object, browser, model

i want to create a new window and automatically (with setInterval) move this window to a new position.
I tried this code but it seems that executes the function defined in setInterval only once...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> BOM </title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var newWin = window.open();
var xcor=0;
var ycor=0;

newWin.resizeTo(500,500);
newWin.document.write("<p>This a new window. I am 500px wide and 500px tall!</p> \n");
setInterval(move(newWin, xcor+=30,ycor+=30),1000);

function move(item,x,y) {
item.moveTo(x,y);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any suggestions?

---

based on teemu's comments i made the following changes to the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> BOM </title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var newWin = window.open();
var x=0;

newWin.resizeTo(500,500);
newWin.document.write("<p>This a new window. I am 500px wide and 500px tall!</p> \n");
setInterval(move(),1000);

function move() {
alert(x+=30);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

again function move (which is only an alert actually) executes only one time?  any other comments?

Comment: At first, `item` is not good variable name, don't use it (it's a protected method name in IE). Secondly, usually browser settings are preventing scripts to move or resize windows, hence the code won't work, unless user allow it to. Thirdly, you need a function reference within `setInterval` argument, not a function call. Notice, that [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) takes some arguments too.

Comment: `move()` is still a function call, it's executed immediately, and `setInterval` sets the return value of `move` (which is `undefined`) to the first argument. `move` would be a reference.

Comment: Thanks! I' ve replaced move() with move and everything works. Even the original which actually moves the window!!!

Comment: You can see moving windows in your browser, but you can't rely on that would happen in any user's browser.